# How to break a sand block without touching it in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm am looking to create a vehicle that can break sand block, although I don't know how. I have the body, the last thing I need is a contraption that can brake sand blocks in Minecraft

Comment: please include relevant version tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frits34000 and a couple other redditors for a good while worked on 'sand quarry' machines - you can find the assorted designs on [r/redstone](https://www.reddit.com/r/redstone/search?q=sand+quarry&restrict_sr=on&include_over_18=on).

The gist of it is to lift the sand block using a sticky piston, and while it is still falling, insert a non-full block like a trapdoor into the space it's trying to land in. Unable to solidify into a regular block, sand drops as item - the machine to do just this is fairly trivial, but there are numerous caveats about making it practical.

Frits34000 published a pretty in-depth tutorial on his designs and ways of dealing with the caveats.

Comment: I tried this with a slab and instead of dropping it just fell on to the the slab, although I couldn't break it while it was on the slab (Because it was in between blocks?). Is this a glitch, or do I need to use a different type of block for it to fall on to.

Comment: @MinecraftNoob Let me guess. Bedrock edition? *sigh* Does it remain in that half-fallen state indefinitely or will it break after 30 seconds?

Comment: Not sure, I try waiting next time I have the chance. Thanks for your help! Also, yes, it is in bedrock edition.

Answer (score 4):

So your trying to make a “bulldozer” vehicle. If sand falls on slabs or anything with a height of less than a block. BUT the only one that is pushable is a slab. So you can simply put slabs in front of the vehicle and move it. Note that any sand NOT above the slabs will not break.